# wait until call of $(item).click done jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to cover jQuery confirmOn  on a function call, This is my code

```
    function MYConfirm(questionText, textYes, textNo) {
        var retData = null;
        $('#co').confirmOn({
            questionText: questionText,
            textYes: textYes,
            textNo: textNo
        }, 'click',function (e, confirmed) {
            retData = confirmed;
        });
        $.Deferred($('#co').click());
        $('#co').promise().done(function () {

           alert(retData);
        });
        while (retData === null) {

        }
        return retData;
    }
```

But I got this exception

> Object [object Object] has no method 'call'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$.Deferred($('#co').click());`?

Comment: I'm trying to trigger on confirmOn method
https://github.com/invetek/jquery-confirmon

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `$.Deferred` must be a function. You're calling the `click` functio rather than passing it as an argument. It should be:

```
$.Deferred($("#co").click);
```

But I'm not sure what you're intending with this code. When `$.Deferred` calls the function, it sets `this` and the first argument to the `Deferred` object. But `.click()` expects its argument to be an event handler function, which it binds as the click handler for the element. There's also not much point in calling `$.Deferred` if you don't assign the value somewhere, so you can add callbacks to it and wait for them to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/invetek/jquery-confirmon) from confirmOn, you need to put the alert statement in the 'click' callback, i.e.

```
$('#co').confirmOn({
        questionText: questionText,
        textYes: textYes,
        textNo: textNo
    }, 'click',function (e, confirmed) {
        retData = confirmed;
        alert(retData);
    });
```

By binding on the $('#co').click(), you'll trigger the event as the element is click itself and not the confirm.